# Define global variable for Models and Controllers at CakePHP 2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

Currently i am using something like this:

```
//at bootstrap.php file
Configure::write('from', 'mymail@mydomain.com')

//at controllers or models files
$var = Configure::read('from')
```

The thing is, i would like to manage that variable through the database to be able to modify it in a simpler way.

I was thinking about doing it with `AppModel` but then it would only be accessible for Models and not controllers.

What should I do in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: CakeDC also offers a Key/Value store mechanism in it's Utils plugin, so you could just use that: https://github.com/CakeDC/utils

If you need to define just one variable and it is a CONSTANT it is much faster for the App to put it in Config/bootstrap.php:
`define('VAR_NAME', value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a separate model / plugin which will be mapped to a configuration table in your database. Then load it through `$uses` statement for controllers and `App::import()` for models.

```
class SystemSetting extends AppModel {

/**
 * Return a list of all settings
 *
 * @access public
 * @return array
 */
    public function getSettings() {        
        return $this->find('all');
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller:

```
class SomeController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array('SystemSetting');

    public function displaySettings() {
        $settings = $this->SystemSetting->getSettings();
        // .. your code
    }
}
```

In model:

```
App::import('Model', 'SystemSettings.SystemSetting');
$settings = new SystemSetting();
$mySettings = $settings->getSettings();
```

This works just fine. Of course, you might also load settings in both `AppController` and `AppModel` to follow the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rule.

Comment: Isn't it weird to call a Model from another Model?

Comment: How about model relationships?

Comment: There's not really a relationship. With what id you connect them?

Comment: You have asked if it isn't weird to call a Model from another Model. It is not, given the example. But in this case, you might also store the settings with `Configure::write` in `AppController` and access them using `Configure::read` in Models.

Comment: Btw, would you have to repeat $settings = new SystemSetting();
$mySettings = $settings->getSettings(); in every method of a Model you want to use it? Is there any other way?

Comment: `ClassRegistry::init('SystemSetting')->getSettings()`

Answer (score 1):

1. create the getSettings in your AppModel
2. in AppController you can write this method:

   ```
   public function getSettings() {
       return $this->{$this->modelClass}->getSettings();
   }
   ```

this way the getSettings() method is available in any model and any controller

any model call:

```
$mysettings = $this->getSettings();
```

any controller call:

```
$mysettings = $this->MODELNAME->getSettings();
```