# CakePHP - Using a different model in current model

Tags: class, cakephp, model

I am creating a custom validation function in my model in CakePHP. After reading similar questions I have understood that I could be using `ClassRegistry::init('Model');` to load a foreign model in my current model. But it doesn't say much more on the syntax and how to actually use it afterwards. This is what I have tried, but nothing "is happening" when I am trying to print the array to see if it contains the right stuff. Basically I want to pull out the User data to use it in my validation.

```
class Booking extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Booking';

    public $validate = array(
        'start_time' => array(
            'noOptionViolation' => array(
                'rule' => 'noOptionViolation',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        ),
    );  

    public function noOptionViolation ($start_time) {

        $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
        $allUsers = $this->User->find('all');
        print_r($allUsers);


    }
```

Is this correct syntax? Can I use all the methods of $this->User just like I would in a controller?

Comment: Actually, something is happening. `$allUsers` contains the expected data, just like it would in a controller. So it seems this is a simple way of fetching foreign model data into a current model. It only leaves the question if I can access all normal model methods. Probably yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use import as detailed on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140816/1081396

```
App::import('Model', 'SystemSettings.SystemSetting');
$settings = new SystemSetting();
$mySettings = $settings->getSettings();
```

In your example it would be like:

```
App::import('Model', 'Users.User');
$user = new User();
$allUsers = $user->find('all');
print_r($allUsers);
```

You could better use the *import* at the beginning of the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I was using "my exemplified models", how would your syntax look like then?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this too to load Models

```
$this->loadModel('User');
```

and access all functions by

```
$this->User
```